# AS3 - How to Draw and Align a Circle?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to draw a circle and align it center. My code doesn't do that:

```
var circle:Shape = new Shape(); // The instance name circle is created
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x990000, 1); // Fill the circle with the color 990000
circle.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000); // Give the ellipse a black, 2 pixels thick line
circle.graphics.drawCircle((stage.stageWidth - 100) / 2, (stage.stageHeight - 100) / 2, 100); // Draw the circle, assigning it a x position, y position, raidius.
circle.graphics.endFill(); // End the filling of the circle
addChild(circle); // Add a child
```

Comment: Works for me. Are you using flash or flex, or what? Where are you putting this code?

Comment: In addition to wraithgarud01's questions, please describe what you're seeing: nothing at all, the circle is drawn but not centered, etc.

Comment: i m using flash cs6, when i test the code, the circle appears but it's not centered. anyway, i did my graphic without coding. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```
drawCircle((stage.stageWidth - 100) / 2, (stage.stageHeight - 100) / 2, 100);
```

The first two parameters of [drawCircle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawCircle%28%29) are the X and Y position of the *center* of the circle, not the top left position of the circle.

If you want your circle in the center of the stage, you just need to put the circle’s center at the same position, so you’d call drawCircle like this:

```
drawCircle(stage.stageWidth / 2, stage.stageHeight / 2, 100);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your approach, although it would work, will just make working with your shape a bit tougher.

consider this approach :

```
var circle:Shape = new Shape();
circle.graphics.clear();
circle.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,100);
circle.graphics.endFill();
addChild(circle);
circle.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
circle.y = stage.stageHeight/ 2;
```

By drawing the circle centered on the 0,0 location in your shape and then placing it via the x and y properties is a far better approach. Suppose you want to move that circle ? Trying to figure out the offsets would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var circle:Shape = new Shape();
circle.graphics.clear();
circle.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,100);
circle.graphics.endFill();
addChild(circle);
circle.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
circle.y = stage.stageHeight/ 2;
```